# Short film about a person receiving creepy phone calls of electronic sounds

Tags: story-identification, short-film

In junior high we watched a short film for a science fiction class. This would have been around 1985, but the film was likely older. I remember it being in color. Could be any time from the sixties to the eighties. Being something we watched in school, it was likely an adaptation of a short story.

A person starts receiving phone calls that are just electronic screeches and noise. The calls keep coming in, harassing the person (can't remember if the person was male or female). Each time the noises are a little less random and eventually you figure out it is an electronic voice learning to speak. I believe in the end it was an alien learning to speak our language.

There might have been a subplot trying to trace the call, but I might be confusing that part with the old Twilight Zone episode.

What I do remember is in the end, whatever is making those phone calls calls the White House.

I remember the movie being very creepy and would like to find it again, or find the original story.

Comment: This was part of the plot of a (recent-ish) Doctor Who episode.

Comment: Sorry, this was from when I was in junior high school. Also, I've never watched Dr. Who. My mom HATED the theme song and would change the channel whenever the show came on:)

Comment: It's B&W and doesn't have the white house twist - but there's a Ray Bradbury documentary that involves an AI that evolved in the phone system. see https://youtu.be/9zHa_udIU9o?t=520 I don't believe this is a story that got published. "Ray Bradbury: Story of a Writer"

Comment: Dial Double Zero is the story for certain, complete with the White House call at the end (Bradbury reads it to the group).

Comment: I got cut off as I was trying to edit. Here is the rest: The film didn't look familiar, but it looks like the story wasn't published (why?) and I don't think there was another film made of the story. I also remember reading his All Of Summer In A Day in class. Is funny, searching Dial Double Zero mainly seems to being up people searching for the film and often with All Of Summer In A Day mentioned. It must have been popular in school. Or everyone in my junior high science fiction class has the same memories as me:)